# PHP Convert Mysql retrived xml data

Tags: php, mysql, xml

lets say that i get this data from a mysql table and it is stored in variable `$xmlFromMysqlRow`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridInstantMessage xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <fromAgentID>d8445b4a-4ed0-4449-bf33-7709443f7f84</fromAgentID>
   <fromAgentName>FABIODK TOPAZ</fromAgentName>
   <toAgentID>70d0f6b8-237d-4863-9aef-96e2c93d5130</toAgentID>
   <dialog>32</dialog>
   <fromGroup>true</fromGroup>
   <message>festa|SPLODERS E PREMIOS PRAS 3  MELHORES ROUPAS, O SPLODER MAIOR VAI ESTAR COM 500 AV$ FIXOS AT� O FIM DA FESTA.
      A PARTIR DAS 20:00 HORAS.
   </message>
   <imSessionID>94809bcd-39c3-4e4d-8405-8829a00ba8ea</imSessionID>
   <offline>0</offline>
   <Position>
      <X>0</X>
      <Y>0</Y>
      <Z>0</Z>
   </Position>
   <binaryBucket>AADYRFtKTtBESb8zdwlEP3+EAA==</binaryBucket>
   <ParentEstateID>0</ParentEstateID>
   <RegionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RegionID>
   <timestamp>1437412707</timestamp>
</GridInstantMessage>
```

How would i get each section of this xml stored into there own varables?
ex i want  everything stored in

```
<message>
</message>
```

to be stored in `$message` how would i do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
preg_match('#<message>(.*?)</message>#sui', $xmlFromMysqlRow, $message);
$message = $message[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper XML parser to robustly and easily extract any part of an XML document. This is one example using [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) :

```
$string = <<<XML
<GridInstantMessage xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <fromAgentID>d8445b4a-4ed0-4449-bf33-7709443f7f84</fromAgentID>
   <fromAgentName>FABIODK TOPAZ</fromAgentName>
   <toAgentID>70d0f6b8-237d-4863-9aef-96e2c93d5130</toAgentID>
   <dialog>32</dialog>
   <fromGroup>true</fromGroup>
   <message>festa|SPLODERS E PREMIOS PRAS 3  MELHORES ROUPAS, O SPLODER MAIOR VAI ESTAR COM 500 AV$ FIXOS AT� O FIM DA FESTA.
      A PARTIR DAS 20:00 HORAS.
   </message>
   <imSessionID>94809bcd-39c3-4e4d-8405-8829a00ba8ea</imSessionID>
   <offline>0</offline>
   <Position>
      <X>0</X>
      <Y>0</Y>
      <Z>0</Z>
   </Position>
   <binaryBucket>AADYRFtKTtBESb8zdwlEP3+EAA==</binaryBucket>
   <ParentEstateID>0</ParentEstateID>
   <RegionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RegionID>
   <timestamp>1437412707</timestamp>
</GridInstantMessage>
XML;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$message = $xml->xpath("//message")[0]->asXML();
echo $message;
```

<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/405627)</kbd>

**output :**

```
<message>festa|SPLODERS E PREMIOS PRAS 3  MELHORES ROUPAS, O SPLODER MAIOR VAI ESTAR COM 500 AV$ FIXOS AT� O FIM DA FESTA.
      A PARTIR DAS 20:00 HORAS.
   </message>
```